# Nativescript error: Build input file cannot be found: 'xxxx/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/metadata-arm64.bin'

Tags: nativescript

I am having problems while building for ios.

Current configuration:
Xcode version: Version 15.2 (15C500b) MacOS version: 14.2.1
Nativescript version: 8.2.3
IOS platform version: 8.3.0

Solution 1: remove arm64 from Excluded Architectures in build settings.
Solution 2: change workspace setting : build location => workspace-relative location